# Centos logrotate not rotating logs daily

Tags: centos7, logrotate

I have a problem i configured daily logrotation for catalina.out in Centos7 but it is not rotated , if force run logrotate it rotates catalina but not automatically on daily basis.

logrotate.d/tomcat configfile:

```
/usr/local/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out
{
    daily
    rotate 30
    missingok
    compress
    copytruncate
}
```

logrotate.conf:

```
    # see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files daily
daily

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
        minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}


# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

logrotate status/debug:

```
    rotating pattern: /usr/local/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out
 after 1 days (30 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /usr/local/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out
  log does not need rotating (log has been already rotated)

"/usr/local/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out" 2019-8-5-9:25:18
```

Comment: @user3788685 so i dont need logrotate to rotate catalina , or how is that going help me?thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In it's default state `tomcat` uses the `log4j`

You should have a file at `/etc/tomcat/log4j.properties` which contains the configuration for the log management.

The default config is (taken from a test box):

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, R 
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.home}/logs/tomcat.log 
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB 
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n 
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG, R
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]=DEBUG, R
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core=DEBUG, R
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.session=DEBUG, R
```

Based on that config the logs will automatically rotate when they grow to 10MB in size, and will keep a maximum of 10 old logs.

You can change these settings as you wish and there are a couple of good guides [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-rotation-example/) and [here](https://docs.lucee.org/guides/installing-lucee/lucee-server-adminstration-windows/implementing-log-rotation-with-log4j.html) which explain all the options, and show how to change to a rolling appender which may be more useful for your needs.

Also log4j takes care of the rotation but if you are doing something like `tail -f cat.out` and the log rotates you will need to re-tail the file to continue watching it else it will just appear to stop mid way (much like the other logs do)

Remember to remove any config you tried to apply via `logrotate` so things don't go wrong later on!

To have a daily rotation you need to use these settings;

> DailyRollingFileAppender
>
> DailyRollingFileAppender rotates log files based on frequency of time
>   allowing customization upto minute. Date Patterns allowed as part of
>   the Appender are as follows:
>
> ```
> yyyy-MM Roll over to new log file beginning on first day of every month
> yyyy-ww Roll over to new log file beginning on first day of every week
> yyyy-MM-dd Roll over daily
> yyyy-MM-dd-a Roll over on midday and midnight
> yyyy-MM-dd-HH Roll over every hour
> yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm Roll over every minute
> ```

That would give a config of:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, fileLogger
log4j.appender.fileLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileLogger.File=example.log
log4j.appender.fileLogger=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileLogger.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
```

Comment: it seems my tomcat doesnt have log4j installed default so i need to download it a then try set the rotation

Comment: from here i download it and install(http://www.us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.96/bin/)

Comment: do you have a `log4j.properties` file in your tomcat path at all? my test and prod boxes where from rpm - I'll see if I can download the tarball tonight and see what's inside.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) - looks like the default tarball uses a different logger. See the section called `Using java.util.logging (default)` and the section below if you wish to switch to log4j. Let me know how you get on and ill update my answer for you.